# Allow for bookmarking in secure shiny apps

Tags: shiny

I have been trying now for several apps to **enable bookmarking and password authentication at the same time**, but always given up assuming that it simply cannot be done. I hope you can convince me otherwise.

Here is a sample app using both the bookmarkButton() and the secure_app() functionality:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymanager)

credentials <- data.frame(
  user = c("shiny", "shinymanager"),
  password = c("azerty", "12345"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)


ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$h2("My secure application"),
  verbatimTextOutput("auth_output"),
  
  bookmarkButton()

)

ui <- function(request) {secure_app(ui, choose_language = TRUE)} # This is the line that throws the error.

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  res_auth <- secure_server(
    check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials)
  )
  
  output$auth_output <- renderPrint({
    reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)
  })
  
  observe({
    print(input$shinymanager_where)
    print(input$shinymanager_language)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server, enableBookmarking = "server")
```

I guess the issue is that the request function transforms the ui output in a way that the secure_server app cannot retrieve its information anymore, and vice versa.

**Question:** Is there a way to combine both options, bookmarking and password authentication?

**I have tried** combining the request function and the secure_app function in different ways, but all have thrown errors so far. I have also searched the web but only found help on issues relating to either the bookmarking or the authentication. Maybe I have used the wrong search terms?

**Why I want to combine both:** In all cases in which I would have liked to have the bookmark option available, RAs were asked to code stuff and submit their coding directly to my personal Dropbox storage. Since I do not want some crawler or random people to be able to store stuff in my Dropbox, I always used the authentication option only, and added some medium complicated and slow bookmarking functionality myself using another Dropbox folder.

Any help or comment would be highly appreciated!